# Can I create a partial index as shown in below?

Tags: postgresql, partial-index

Assume there is a table with 5 columns (id ,first_name (text),last_name(text), product_name(text) and available(boolean)).

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "idx-firstname-lower + product_name" 
  ON persons (LOWER(first_name), product_name) WHERE available;
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It was executed without errors.

Comment: Then why do you ask "can I create such an index" - you obviously can.

Comment: Actually,What I wanted to know was that it was theoretically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create that index, although I would reconsider the index name. Use a standard conforming name like `mytab_lower_firstname_productname_idx`.